# How to scrape value attribute from li in un-ordered lists with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using `BeautifulSoup` to extract values ​​from an unordered list but I'm not able to. These are the steps I do:

1- I run a `find_all()` to the web looking for the ul elements with class "cols"

```
results = soup.find_all('ul', class_='cols')
```

2- It returns:

```
[<ul class="cols"> <li value="weapon_knife_survival_bowie">Bowie Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_butterfly">Butterfly Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_falchion">Falchion Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_flip">Flip Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_gut">Gut Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_tactical">Huntsman Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_m9_bayonet">M9 Bayonet</li> <li value="weapon_bayonet">Bayonet</li> <li value="weapon_knife_karambit">Karambit</li> <li value="weapon_knife_push">Shadow Daggers</li> <li value="weapon_knife_stiletto">Stiletto Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_ursus">Ursus Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_gypsy_jackknife">Navaja Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_widowmaker">Talon Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_css">Classic Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_cord">Paracord Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_canis">Survival Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_outdoor">Nomad Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_skeleton">Skeleton Knife</li> </ul>, <ul class="cols"> <li value="weapon_hkp2000">P2000</li> <li value="weapon_usp_silencer">USP-S</li> <li value="weapon_glock">Glock-18</li> <li value="weapon_p250">P250</li> <li value="weapon_fiveseven">FN57</li> <li value="weapon_cz75a">CZ75-Auto</li> <li value="weapon_tec9">Tec-9</li> <li value="weapon_revolver">R8 Revolver</li> <li value="weapon_deagle">Desert Eagle</li> <li value="weapon_elite">Dual Berettas</li> </ul>, <ul class="cols"> <li value="weapon_galilar">Galil AR</li> <li value="weapon_scar20">SCAR-20</li> <li value="weapon_awp">AWP</li> <li value="weapon_ak47">AK-47</li> <li value="weapon_famas">FAMAS</li> <li value="weapon_m4a1">M4A4</li> <li value="weapon_m4a1_silencer">M4A1-S</li> <li value="weapon_sg556">SG 553</li> <li value="weapon_ssg08">SSG 08</li> <li value="weapon_aug">AUG</li> <li value="weapon_g3sg1">G3SG1</li> </ul>, <ul class="cols"> <li value="weapon_p90">P90</li> <li value="weapon_mac10">MAC-10</li> <li value="weapon_ump45">UMP-45</li> <li value="weapon_mp7">MP7</li> <li value="weapon_bizon">PP-Bizon</li> <li value="weapon_mp9">MP9</li> <li value="weapon_mp5sd">MP5-SD</li> </ul>, <ul class="cols"> <li value="weapon_bloodhound_gloves">Bloodhound Gloves</li> <li value="weapon_driver_gloves">Driver Gloves</li> <li value="weapon_hand_wraps">Hand Wraps</li> <li value="weapon_moto_gloves">Moto Gloves</li> <li value="weapon_specialist_gloves">Specialist Gloves</li> <li value="weapon_sport_gloves">Sport Gloves</li> <li value="weapon_hydra_gloves">Hydra Gloves</li> <li value="weapon_brokenfang_gloves">Broken Fang Glove</li> </ul>, <ul class="cols" style="width:318px;overflow-y:auto;max-height: 385px;padding-bottom: 200px"> <li value="crate_sticker_pack_community2022_capsule">Espionage</li> <li value="sticker_tournament20">Rio 2022</li> <li value="crate_sticker_pack_csgo10_capsule">CSGO 10</li> <li value="sticker_tournament19">Antwerp 2022</li> <li value="crate_sticker_pack_spring2022_capsule">Boardroom</li> <li value="crate_sticker_pack_bf2042_capsule_lootlist">Battlefield 2042</li> <li value="sticker_tournament18">Stockholm 2021</li> <li value="crate_sticker_pack_riptide_surfshop_lootlist">Riptide Surf Shop</li> <li value="crate_sticker_pack_op_riptide_capsule_lootlist">Operation Riptide</li> <li value="sticker_community2021">2021 Community</li> <li value="poorly_drawn">Poorly Drawn</li> <li value="sticker_2020rmr">2020RMR</li> <li value="sticker_broken_fang">Broken Fang</li> <li value="sticker_recoil">Recoil</li> <li value="warhammer_sticker">Warhammer 40K</li> <li value="alyx_sticker_capsule">HL:Alyx</li> <li value="halo_capsule">Halo</li> <li value="shattered_web">Shattered Web</li> <li value="cs20_capsule">CS20</li> <li value="2019_StarLadder_Berlin_Major">Berlin 2019</li> <li value="crate_sticker_pack_chicken_capsule_lootlist">Chicken</li> <li value="crate_sticker_pack_feral_predators_capsule_lootlist">Feral Predators</li> <li value="sticker_tournament15">Katowice 2019</li> <li value="skill_groups_capsule">Skill Group</li> <li value="sticker_tournament14">London 2018</li> <li value="sticker_tournament13">Boston 2018</li> <li value="sticker_tournament12">Krakow 2017</li> <li value="sticker_tournament11">Atlanta 2017</li> <li value="sticker_tournament10">Cologne 2016</li> <li value="sticker_tournament9">Columbus 2016</li> <li value="sticker_tournament8">DreamHack 2015</li> <li value="sticker_tournament7">Cologne 2015</li> <li value="sticker_tournament6">Katowice 2015</li> <li value="sticker_tournament5">DreamHack 2014</li> <li value="sticker_tournament4">Cologne 2014</li> <li value="sticker_tournament3">Katowice 2014</li> <li value="crate_sticker_pack_comm2018_01_capsule_lootlist">Community 2018</li> <li value="crate_sticker_pack01">Sticker 1</li> <li value="crate_sticker_pack02">Sticker 2</li> <li value="crate_sticker_pack_enfu_capsule_lootlist">Enfu Sticker</li> <li value="crate_sticker_pack_illuminate_capsule_01_lootlist">Perfect World 1</li> <li value="crate_sticker_pack_illuminate_capsule_02_lootlist">Perfect World 2</li> <li value="crate_sticker_pack_community01">Community 1</li> <li value="crate_sticker_pack_bestiary_capsule_lootlist">Bestiary</li> <li value="crate_sticker_pack_slid3_capsule_lootlist">Slid3</li> <li value="crate_sticker_pack_sugarface_capsule_lootlist">Sugarface</li> <li value="crate_sticker_pack_pinups_capsule_lootlist">Pinups</li> <li value="crate_sticker_pack_team_roles_capsule_lootlist">Team Roles</li> <li value="sticker_other">Other stickers</li> </ul>, <ul class="cols"> <li value="csgo_type_tool">Tools</li> <li value="csgo_type_spray">Spray</li> <li value="csgo_type_collectible">Collectibles</li> <li value="csgo_type_ticket">Passes</li> <li value="csgo_tool_gifttag">Gifts</li> <li value="csgo_type_musickit">Music kits</li> <li value="csgo_type_weaponcase">Weapon Cases</li> <li value="csgo_tool_weaponcase_keytag">Keys</li> <li value="csgo_tool_patch">Patch</li> </ul>]
```

3- From there I want to extract the values ​​of li (only what is inside "li value=" ) but I am not able. I try:

```
for result in results:
    element = result.find('li')
    print(element)
```

but it only prints a small part of the ones in the list, many others are missing (plus I only need the "value" field, nothing else):

```
<li value="weapon_knife_survival_bowie">Bowie Knife</li>
<li value="weapon_hkp2000">P2000</li>
<li value="weapon_galilar">Galil AR</li>
<li value="weapon_p90">P90</li>
<li value="weapon_bloodhound_gloves">Bloodhound Gloves</li>
<li value="crate_sticker_pack_community2022_capsule">Espionage</li>
<li value="csgo_type_tool">Tools</li>
```

What I need is to get these values:

```
weapon_knife_survival_bowie
weapon_knife_butterfly
weapon_knife_falchion
weapon_knife_flip
...
and so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find` method is intended to return only one result. To get all instances you should use the `find_all` method.

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

Edit:

To get all the `li` items (and their 'value' attributes):

```
value_attributes = []

for result in results:
    li = result.find_all("li")
    for item in li:
        value_attributes.append(item["value"])
```

With this I'm able to get the result that you want in the format of a list that includes all value attributes of all list tags:

```
['weapon_knife_survival_bowie', 'weapon_knife_butterfly', 'weapon_knife_falchion', 'weapon_knife_flip', 'weapon_knife_gut', 'weapon_knife_tactical', 'weapon_knife_m9_bayonet', 'weapon_bayonet', 'weapon_knife_karambit', 'weapon_knife_push', 'weapon_knife_stiletto', 'weapon_knife_ursus', 'weapon_knife_gypsy_jackknife', 'weapon_knife_widowmaker', 'weapon_knife_css', 'weapon_knife_cord', 'weapon_knife_canis', 'weapon_knife_outdoor', 'weapon_knife_skeleton', 'weapon_hkp2000', 'weapon_usp_silencer', 'weapon_glock', 'weapon_p250', 'weapon_fiveseven', 'weapon_cz75a', 'weapon_tec9', 'weapon_revolver', 'weapon_deagle', 'weapon_elite', 'weapon_galilar', 'weapon_scar20', 'weapon_awp', 'weapon_ak47', 'weapon_famas', 'weapon_m4a1', 'weapon_m4a1_silencer', 'weapon_sg556', 'weapon_ssg08', 'weapon_aug', 'weapon_g3sg1', 'weapon_p90', 'weapon_mac10', 'weapon_ump45', 'weapon_mp7', 'weapon_bizon', 'weapon_mp9', 'weapon_mp5sd', 'weapon_bloodhound_gloves', 'weapon_driver_gloves', 'weapon_hand_wraps', 'weapon_moto_gloves', 'weapon_specialist_gloves', 'weapon_sport_gloves', 'weapon_hydra_gloves', 'weapon_brokenfang_gloves', 'crate_sticker_pack_community2022_capsule', 'sticker_tournament20', 'crate_sticker_pack_csgo10_capsule', 'sticker_tournament19', 'crate_sticker_pack_spring2022_capsule', 'crate_sticker_pack_bf2042_capsule_lootlist', 'sticker_tournament18', 'crate_sticker_pack_riptide_surfshop_lootlist', 'crate_sticker_pack_op_riptide_capsule_lootlist', 'sticker_community2021', 'poorly_drawn', 'sticker_2020rmr', 'sticker_broken_fang', 'sticker_recoil', 'warhammer_sticker', 'alyx_sticker_capsule', 'halo_capsule', 'shattered_web', 'cs20_capsule', '2019_StarLadder_Berlin_Major', 'crate_sticker_pack_chicken_capsule_lootlist', 'crate_sticker_pack_feral_predators_capsule_lootlist', 'sticker_tournament15', 'skill_groups_capsule', 'sticker_tournament14', 'sticker_tournament13', 'sticker_tournament12', 'sticker_tournament11', 'sticker_tournament10', 'sticker_tournament9', 'sticker_tournament8', 'sticker_tournament7', 'sticker_tournament6', 'sticker_tournament5', 'sticker_tournament4', 'sticker_tournament3', 'crate_sticker_pack_comm2018_01_capsule_lootlist', 'crate_sticker_pack01', 'crate_sticker_pack02', 'crate_sticker_pack_enfu_capsule_lootlist', 'crate_sticker_pack_illuminate_capsule_01_lootlist', 'crate_sticker_pack_illuminate_capsule_02_lootlist', 'crate_sticker_pack_community01', 'crate_sticker_pack_bestiary_capsule_lootlist', 'crate_sticker_pack_slid3_capsule_lootlist', 'crate_sticker_pack_sugarface_capsule_lootlist', 'crate_sticker_pack_pinups_capsule_lootlist', 'crate_sticker_pack_team_roles_capsule_lootlist', 'sticker_other', 'csgo_type_tool', 'csgo_type_spray', 'csgo_type_collectible', 'csgo_type_ticket', 'csgo_tool_gifttag', 'csgo_type_musickit', 'csgo_type_weaponcase', 'csgo_tool_weaponcase_keytag', 'csgo_tool_patch']
```

Comment: I can´t use a find_all method into my for in because the BeautifulSoup object is not callable.

Comment: I can't say for sure why you can't call find_all there but I can't comment further without seeing the entire code. I've edited my response with the snippet that gets the information that you want in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You are close to your goal - Iterate your ResultSet one more time or select your elements in another way for example with [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) - Select all `<li>` that are in an `<ul>`:

```
for e in soup.select('ul.cols li'):
    print(e.get('value'))
```

or more specific, that also has an attribute `value`:

```
for e in soup.select('ul.cols li[value]'):
    print(e.get('value'))
```

or based on yur approach:

```
for result in soup.find_all('ul', class_='cols'):
    for e in result.find_all('li'):
        print(e.get('value'))
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<ul class="cols"> <li value="weapon_knife_survival_bowie">Bowie Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_butterfly">Butterfly Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_falchion">Falchion Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_flip">Flip Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_gut">Gut Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_tactical">Huntsman Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_m9_bayonet">M9 Bayonet</li> <li value="weapon_bayonet">Bayonet</li> <li value="weapon_knife_karambit">Karambit</li> <li value="weapon_knife_push">Shadow Daggers</li> <li value="weapon_knife_stiletto">Stiletto Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_ursus">Ursus Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_gypsy_jackknife">Navaja Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_widowmaker">Talon Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_css">Classic Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_cord">Paracord Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_canis">Survival Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_outdoor">Nomad Knife</li> <li value="weapon_knife_skeleton">Skeleton Knife</li> </ul>
<ul class="cols"> <li value="weapon_hkp2000">P2000</li> <li value="weapon_usp_silencer">USP-S</li> <li value="weapon_glock">Glock-18</li> <li value="weapon_p250">P250</li> <li value="weapon_fiveseven">FN57</li> <li value="weapon_cz75a">CZ75-Auto</li> <li value="weapon_tec9">Tec-9</li> <li value="weapon_revolver">R8 Revolver</li> <li value="weapon_deagle">Desert Eagle</li> <li value="weapon_elite">Dual Berettas</li> </ul>
<ul class="cols"> <li value="weapon_galilar">Galil AR</li> <li value="weapon_scar20">SCAR-20</li> <li value="weapon_awp">AWP</li> <li value="weapon_ak47">AK-47</li> <li value="weapon_famas">FAMAS</li> <li value="weapon_m4a1">M4A4</li> <li value="weapon_m4a1_silencer">M4A1-S</li> <li value="weapon_sg556">SG 553</li> <li value="weapon_ssg08">SSG 08</li> <li value="weapon_aug">AUG</li> <li value="weapon_g3sg1">G3SG1</li> </ul>
<ul class="cols"> <li value="weapon_p90">P90</li> <li value="weapon_mac10">MAC-10</li> <li value="weapon_ump45">UMP-45</li> <li value="weapon_mp7">MP7</li> <li value="weapon_bizon">PP-Bizon</li> <li value="weapon_mp9">MP9</li> <li value="weapon_mp5sd">MP5-SD</li> </ul>
<ul class="cols"> <li value="weapon_bloodhound_gloves">Bloodhound Gloves</li> <li value="weapon_driver_gloves">Driver Gloves</li> <li value="weapon_hand_wraps">Hand Wraps</li> <li value="weapon_moto_gloves">Moto Gloves</li> <li value="weapon_specialist_gloves">Specialist Gloves</li> <li value="weapon_sport_gloves">Sport Gloves</li> <li value="weapon_hydra_gloves">Hydra Gloves</li> <li value="weapon_brokenfang_gloves">Broken Fang Glove</li> </ul>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for e in soup.select('ul.cols li'):
    print(e.get('value'))
```